# get list of all folders in firebase storage using python

Tags: python, django, firebase-storage

i'm using **django** app and [firebase-admin](https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/)  and i have a files and sub folders(nested folders) as shown in image[image: img]
each folder has its own files and folders.
**i want to get a List of all folders and files inside each root folder** ,
my code is :

```
service_account_key = 'mysak.json'
cred = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(service_account_key)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': 'myBucketUrl'
})
bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = list(bucket.list_blobs()) #this is returning all objects and files in storage not for the folder i want
```

for example i want all files in `first_stage/math` so i can get a url for each file
i have also read the docs about firebase storage and there is no such a method

Comment: what module do you use? Maybe it needs some option - `.list_blobs(...option...)`?

Comment: some pages suggests something like `.list_blobs(prefix="first_stage/math")` [List objects  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python)

Comment: thanks that worked for me ! please consider write it as answer so i can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation [List objects | Cloud Storage | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) you can do something like

```
bucket.list_blobs(prefix="first_stage/math")
```